# how to set bootstrap tab to auto width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap tabs being generated dynamically from a datasource, currently I have set the tab widths to a fixed width, but some of the names being returned are longer then what I set the width for.

Is there any way to set the width that it adjusts to the length of the name?

IE if a name being returned is Cooking Room then the tab should adjust to fit it

The tabs are generated with this

```
function CreateTabs(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.Room.Areas.length; i++) {
        $('#List').append("<li id='" + data.Room.Areas[i].AreaID + "' class='nav-item not-active'><a class='nav-link' href='" + data.Room.Areas[i].AreaName + "' data-toggle='tab'>" + data.Room.Areas[i].AreaName + "</a></li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear friend as I know by default tabs adjust to fit with text. Please remove fixed width and check this sample.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active Active Active Active Active Active Active Active Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link Link Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```